# Linked list odd and even position swapping

Tags: c, linked-list

I wanted to do a singly linked list manipulation like this: source list[1->2->3->4->5->6] and result should be [2->1->4->3->6->5]. Basically I need to swap odd and even link positions. Any help would be much appreciated

```
list * odd_even_swap(list *head)
{
  list * prev, *next, *temp;
  if(head && head->next) {
    prev = head;
    next = head->next;
    head = next;
  } else {
    return NULL;
  }
  while(next) {
    temp = next->next;
    prev->next = temp;
    next->next = prev;
    next = temp;
  }
  return head;
}
```

Input: 1->2->3->4->5->6
Output I got is: 2->1->

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: Can you please post how you are using this function specifically? What code are you using to call it?

Comment: What will happen if you have an odd number of elements?

Comment: You forgot to update `prev` in the loop.

Comment: Note the linked duplicate adapted for this question would look [something like this](http://pastebin.com/MjUjXvax). Best of luck.